# Moodle inicia una descarga pero antes de finalizar dice "fallido"

Tags: archivo

Migré moodle dentro de un mismo hosting "hostinger", pero cuando quiero descargar un archivo de un curso docente/estudiante/ o administrador inicia la descarga pero antes de finalizar dice "fallido", solo me pasa con los archivos ya existentes, pero con los nuevos no pasa nada los descarga con normalidad intenté descargar un archivo que esperaba se descargue y sale fallido antes de finalizar la descarga